# Getting the error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined" when uploading a video using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

The task is to choose a video file from the desktop and upload it to the site. Then this video file will be automatically uploaded to a Youtube channel you have provided using GCD.

I am getting the error as "react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
at handleSubmit (App.js:30)"

Below is the backend code :

```
const express = require("express")

const youtube = require("youtube-api");

const uuid = require("uuid")

const cors = require("cors");

const open = require("open");

const multer = require("multer")

const fs = require("fs")

const credentials = require("./GCD credentials.json.json")
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './',
    filename(req, file, cb){
        const newFileName = `${uuid()}-${file.originalname}`
        cb (null, newFileName);
    }
})

const uploadVideo = multer({
    storage : storage
}).single("videoFile")

app.post('/upload' , uploadVideo, (req, res) =>{
    if (req.file) {
         const filename = req.file.filename;
         const {title, description} = req.body;

    open(oAuth.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type : 'offline',
        scope: "https://wwww.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.uplaod",
        state : JSON.stringify({
            filename,
            title,
            description
        })
    }))
}
})

app.get('/oauth2callback', (req,res) =>{
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/Success")
const {filename, title, description}  = JSON.parse(req.query.state);

oAuth.getToken(req.query.code, (err, tokens) =>{
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    oAuth.setCredentials(tokens);
    youtube.insert({
        resorces:{
            // Again in documentation
            snippet: {title, description},
            status : {privacyStatus : 'private'}
        },
        part : 'snippet,status',
        media: {
            // fs(file sysytem) is used for uploading
            body : fs.createReadStream(filename)
        }
    },(err, data) =>{
        console.log("Done finally. You acn exit");
        process.exit();
    })
})

})

const oAuth = youtube.authenticate({
    type: "oauth",
    client_id : credentials.web.client_id,
    client_secret : credentials.web.client_secret,
    redirect_url : credentials.web.redirect_uris[0],
})

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`App is running ${port}`);
})
```

Here is the frontend code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const axios = require('axios').default;

const App = () => {

  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    file: null,
  });

  const handleChange = (event) =>{
    const inputValue = event.target.name === "file" ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [event.target.name] : inputValue
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
     event.preventDefault();

    const videoData = new FormData ();

    videoData.append("videoFile".form.file);
    videoData.append("title".form.title);
    videoData.append("description".form.description);

    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/upload", videoData)
  .then(response =>{
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  }

  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Tech Pose Tube !!!</h1>
      <form className="w-25 " onSubmit  = {handleSubmit}>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputTitle">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter the title of your video"
            onChange = {handleChange}
            name = "title"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputDescription">Description</label>
          <textarea
           type="text" 
           class="form-control" 
           onChange = {handleChange}
           name = "description"
           />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Choose your video file</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            accept = "video/mp4"
            onChange = {handleChange}
            name = "file"
          />
          <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said:

```
"react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined at handleSubmit (App.js:30)"
```

It's the problem with your frontend code. I saw a typo in this part, you should replace "." by ","

```
    videoData.append("videoFile".form.file); //---> should be videoData.append("videoFile", form.file);
    videoData.append("title".form.title); // same as above
    videoData.append("description".form.description); // same as above
```

The document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) in case you need it.

Another issue, you're listening on port 3000 in the backend code, so the frontend code to send request should be :

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/upload", videoData);
```

Comment: Thanks I got it. But a new error comes as "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)". Can you please look at it ?

Comment: I found a new issue and I edited my answer

Comment: I have made all the changes, but still error comes as "xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3000/upload net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84" . Can you please look into it?

Comment: weird, this likely a CORS error but you already use `cors` module. You may need to check the request in the Chrome DevTools, network tab.

Comment: I have checked the network tab and found "Cannot POST /upload" there. Also in my backend a strange error comes as "const newFileName = `${uuid()}-${file.originalname}`
                               ^
TypeError: uuid is not a function"

Comment: You can see the document of `uuid` package  [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid). An example : `const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'`